# Using data from API using fetch() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, fetch-api

I have created a component that will fetch data from an API. The code below works fine and I can see that the data has been pulled through when using dev tools in chrome however I cannot seem to access the arrays to display what I need from them.

This is what I have at the moment however I get an 'item' is not defined error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FetchConnectApi extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      response: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/jobs')
    .then(response => { if (!response.ok)
      { throw Error("Network request failed") }
      return response;
    })
    .then(jobs => jobs.json())
    .then(jobs => {
      this.setState({
        response: jobs
      })
    }, () => {
      this.setState({
        requestFailed: true
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.requestFailed) return <p>Failed!</p>
    if (!this.state.results) return <p>Loading...</p>
    return (
      <div> this.state.response.map(item => <h1>{item}</h1>)
      </div> 
    )
  } 
}

export default FetchConnectApi;
```

Data being pulled through:

```
State
response:
Array[2]
0:
{…}
job_class:
"class"
 job_client:
"client"
job_contractor:
"contractor"
job_created:
"created"
job_details:
"details"
job_due:
"due"
job_files:
"files"
job_id:
1
job_name:
"George 123"
job_status:
"status"
1:
{…}
job_class:
"KYC"
job_client:
"Ashgrovecompliance"
job_contractor:
"d"
job_created:
"09/02/2018"
job_details:
"Testing API again"
job_due:
"12/02/2018"
job_files:
"d"
job_id:
2
job_name:
"George test modified"
job_status:
"d"
```

Comment: How does your fetched data look like?

Comment: State
response:
Array[2]
0:
{…}
job_class:
"class"
job_client:
"client"
job_contractor:
"contractor"
job_created:
"created"
job_details:
"details"
job_due:
"due"
job_files:
"files"
job_id:
1
job_name:
"George 123"
job_status:
"status"
1:
{…}
job_class:
"KYC"
job_client:
"Ashgrovecompliance"
job_contractor:
"d"
job_created:
"09/02/2018"
job_details:
"Testing API again"
job_due:
"12/02/2018"
job_files:
"d"
job_id:
2
job_name:
"George test modified"
job_status:
"d"

Comment: please edit your question and do not insert your data inside a  comment.

Comment: apologies, question edited.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting your `response` array to an object.

```
this.setState({
  response: jobs
})
```

You probably want to `push` onto the array if that's what you want to work with.  And since you're using `map`, you appear to want an array.  Additionally, you want to enclose js in jsx with `{}` so it's read as js.